# How to remove a Heroku review app build pack

Tags: heroku, buildpack, heroku-cli

I don't want to remove it from the production app or even staging. Deleting it from the Settings on Heroku doesn't seem to work, it'll just show up again when I try to rebuild the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `app.json` file, you can find a section `buildpacks`. That's where you can set which buildpacks will be used for your review apps.